# Using the Correct Type-Constrained Variants with Swift Generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, type-constraints

Given a type with two generics and multiple type constrained initializers:

```
struct ComposableRequest <T, U> {

    init() {
        self.t = defaultT()
        self.u = defaultU()
    }
    
    var t: T?
    var u: U?

    private func defaultT() -> T? {
        nil
    }
    
    private func defaultT() -> T? where T == String {
        "Test1"
    }
    
    private func defaultT() -> T? where T == Int {
        1
    }
    
    private func defaultU() -> U? {
        nil
    }
    
    private func defaultU() -> U? where U == String {
        "Test2"
    }
    
    private func defaultU() -> U? where U == Int {
        2
    }
}
```

I can't seem to ever get the type constrained versions of the default-plating methods called:

```
let first = ComposableRequest<String, Int>()
print(first.t) // I'd expect this to be `"Test1"`, but its nil!
print(first.u) // I'd expect this to be `2`, but its nil!
```

How does Swift decide which type-constrained methods to use when multiple type constrained options would satisfy? Should this code even compile if the selected method is ambiguous? How can the more-specialized versions to get called?

Answer (score 3):

The problem at this point is that there is hardly anything generic left about what you're doing. For that very reason, you can easily get the result you are after *without* trying to use `where` clauses as a sort of fake overloading:

```
struct MyGeneric<T, U> {

    init() {
        self.t = self.defaultT()
        self.u = self.defaultU()
    }
    
    var t: T?
    var u: U?

    private func defaultT() -> T? {
        if T.self is String.Type {
            return Optional("Test" as! T)
        }
        if T.self is Int.Type {
            return Optional(1 as! T)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    private func defaultU() -> U? {
        if U.self is String.Type {
            return Optional("Test2" as! U)
        }
        if U.self is Int.Type {
            return Optional(2 as! U)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change `Optional("Test" as! T)` etc into `"Test" as? T`, can't you?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes! But only because in this particular example we're outputting an Optional. If we weren't, someone would have to force-cast something some time. :) Basically I just wrote it this way in order to prevent the force-cast from generating a warning.

Answer (score 2):

Overloads are chosen statically at compile time. That, plus the fact that struct methods are statically dispatched, means that which `defaultT`/`defaultU` to call is already decided when the *compiler* sees:

```
self.t = defaultT()
self.u = defaultU()
```

not when those lines are *run*. From the compiler's perspective, `T` and `U` could be any type, so the best method to choose here is the ones that return `nil`.

One way to call the other methods, is to constrain the initialiser as well:

```
init() where T == String, U == Int {
    self.t = defaultT()
    self.u = defaultU()
}

init() where T == Int, U == String {
    self.t = defaultT()
    self.u = defaultU()
}

init() where U == String {
    self.t = defaultT()
    self.u = defaultU()
}

init() where U == Int {
    self.t = defaultT()
    self.u = defaultU()
}

init() where T == String {
    self.t = defaultT()
    self.u = defaultU()
}

init() where T == Int {
    self.t = defaultT()
    self.u = defaultU()
}

init() {
    self.t = defaultT()
    self.u = defaultU()
}
```

But that's a lot of repetition... Each time you want to add support for a new type in addition to `String` and `Int`, you need to add even more initialisers...

One better way to do this would be to move the `defaultX` methods into a protocol called `HasDefault`:

```
protocol HasDefaults {
    static func defaults() -> Self
}
```

```
extension String: HasDefaults {
    static func defaults() -> [String] {
        ["Test1", "Test2"]
    }
    
}

extension Int: HasDefaults {
    static func defaults() -> [Int] {
        [1, 2]
    }
}

struct MyGeneric<T, U> {
    init() {
        t = nil
        u = nil
    }
    
    init() where T: HasDefaults {
        t = T.defaults()[0]
        u = nil
    }
    
    init() where U: HasDefaults {
        t = nil
        u = U.defaults()[1]
    }
    
    init() where T: HasDefaults, U: HasDefaults {
        t = T.defaults()[0]
        u = U.defaults()[1]
    }
    
    var t: T?
    var u: U?
}
```

You might even choose to not allow any non-`HasDefaults` type to be used as `T` or `U`. That way you only need one initialiser.